# SQL find error value on table or skip error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have over thousands data on my table, in this case i want to change data type hexadecimal value into integer. here's table example :

```
hex           int
000001CA   |   
000001D3   |
000001F5   |
```

this is my query :

```
UPDATE table
SET int = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, hex, 2))
```

when i execute the query i get error message that some value error failed converting data type but i dont know which one because there are many data on the table. Is there a way to find the error value or just skip the error and continue other value ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: In your query, is the keyword table representing the table name ? Also, please copy paste the whole error(the original one...)

Comment: what's the data type of `hex` within the table creation DDL ?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change it to:

```
UPDATE table
SET int = TRY_CONVERT(int, TRY_CONVERT(varbinary, hex, 2))
```

[TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will attempt to convert the value and if it cannot, return a NULL.

Another option is to select the hex values from your table and use

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, TRY_CONVERT(varbinary, hex, 2)) IS NOT NULL
```

to get all the valid, convert-able values. Then you can run your update knowing it is only using valid values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT` to find the records that are failing to convert. This function will return **NULL** if conversion fails.

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
select t.*
from table t
where try_convert(int, CONVERT(varbinary, t.hex, 2)) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your Update statement except for the table name(`table`). Even a table with this name cannot be created, but if you convert it to `[table]`, then the statement will be succesfull :

```
UPDATE [table]
   SET int = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varbinary, hex, 2)); -- case hex is type VARCHAR

SELECT *
  FROM [table];

int hex
458 000001CA
467 000001D3
501 000001F5
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE [table]
   SET int = CONVERT(int, hex) -- case hex is type VARBINARY

SELECT *
  FROM [table];

int hex
458 0x000001CA
467 0x000001D3
501 0x000001F5
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=45074c371e5a9577dad54b957ffaf284)</kbd>

***P.S.:**`TRY_CONVERT(int, TRY_CONVERT(varbinary, hex, 2))`,which's stated within the other answers, would return the same result.*